# trying to send data from python to html

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

I'm scraping some content and trying to display on html page but it display nothing when i try to run jinja loop for dictionary i sent from python file, it runs every variable separately but not running loop on dictionary

Python dictionary i'm trying to display

```
dictionary = dict(
        [('page_title', url), ('title', title), ('anchor', anchor),
         ('images', images)])
```

Html code with jinja tags

```
<div id="dictionary">
{% for items in dictionary %}
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img src="{{ items.images }}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ items.title }}">
    <div class="card-body">
        <a href="{{ items.anchor }}" class="btn btn-primary"><h5 class="card-title">{{ items.title }}</h5></a>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: change your data structure to `dictionary= {'page_title': url,"title":title......}`

Comment: already tried , not working

Answer (score 2):

No any for loop is needed. Directly, you can use `dictionary` data

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img src="{{ dictionary.images }}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ dictionary.title }}">
    <div class="card-body">
        <a href="{{ dictionary.anchor }}" class="btn btn-primary"><h5 class="card-title">{{ dictionary.title }}</h5></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tried but not working

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

You can create [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) like this:

templatetags/tags.py

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

your_html.html:

```
<div id="dictionary">
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img src="{{ dictionary|get_item:'images' }}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ dictionary|get_item:'title' }}">
    <div class="card-body">
        <a href="{{ dictionary|get_item:'anchor' }}" class="btn btn-primary"><h5 class="card-title">{{ dictionary|get_item:'title' }}</h5></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AbdulSubhan did tried mine ?

Comment: its now giving this error :
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
Exception Location: /Users/aaa/gsmarena/gsmApp/templatetags/tags.py, line 7, in get_item

Comment: How are you returning `dictionary` from your view ?

Comment: dictionary = dict(
            [('page_title', url), ('title', title), ('anchor', anchor),
             ('images', images)])

    return render(request, 'searchresult.html', dictionary)

Comment: error occurring in tags.py you asked me to create

Comment: It is not necessary the issue would be in tags your template would be sending wrong data to tags. Change view context to `render(request, 'searchresult.html', {'dictionary': dictionary})` and try.

Comment: its working now , but another problem . its set of values so i need it to display through loop like image, url and title in one block then these in other blocks

Comment: If it fixed your issue you mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: You can use `{% for img in dictionary|get_item:"images" %}` and show it `{{ img }}`

Comment: is there. a way i can run one loop for all variables , something like this ?
{% for img in dictionary|get_item %}
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="{{ img.images }}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ img.title }}">
        <div class="card-body">
            <a href="{{ img.anchor }}" class="btn btn-primary"><h5 class="card-title">{{ img.title }}</h5></a>
        </div>
    </div>
        {% endfor %}